# Regex: All alphanumeric with at most one dot in the middle

Tags: java, regex

I want to have a regex that

1. contains alphanumeric characters and at most one dot
2. only start with alpha character
3. doesn't finish with dot

I tried:

```
 ^(?=.{8,})[a-zA-Z0-9^]([-_.][a-zA-Z0-9]*)?[a-zA-Z0-9^]$
```

which doesn't work, i.e. it doesn't match `kjh.jhhhmnbmnb`

Comment: Can you define "doesn't work?" Can you give some examples of inputs that it fails for?

Comment: I added a failing example to the question.

Comment: Wouldn't it be something like `[A-Za-z0-9]+(\.[A-Za-z0-9]+)?$` (using .NET syntax)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following regex:

```
^(?!.*\\..*\\..*)[A-Za-z]([A-Za-z0-9.]*[A-Za-z0-9])?$
```

**Explanation:**

```
(?!.*\\..*\\..*)   Assert that two periods do not occur
[A-Za-z]           Match an initial alpha character
(
[A-Za-z0-9.]*      Match an alphanumeric or dot zero or more times
[A-Za-z0-9]        Match a terminal alphanumeric only once
)?                 The entire quantity occurring zero or once
```

**Code sample:**

```
String input = "a23.d";
if (input.matches("^(?!.*\\..*\\..*)[A-Za-z]([A-Za-z0-9.]*[A-Za-z0-9])?$")) {
    System.out.println("match");
}
```

Comment: Doesn't `[A-Za-z0-9.]*` let the string have more than one dot ?

Comment: @ArianHosseinzadeh No, it _doesn't_ match `ab..s`, check this demo: http://rextester.com/TUAI93651

Comment: @ArianHosseinzadeh I think you may not understand how lookaheads work.  Once the regex reaches `[A-Za-z0-9.]*` we have _already_ asserted that only zero or one dot occurs in the string.  There cannot be two or more dots.

Comment: @ArianHosseinzadeh No...you made a mistake.  In regex101 we use _single_ backslashes to escape things.  In Java we use _double_ backslahes.  Look at [this corrected Regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/vMDD4G/2).

Comment: Why there are two `\\..` in the regex ? what does each dot do ?

Comment: The quantity `\\.` matches a literal dot, and then `.*` matches any character in any quantity.  Note that in Regex101 you would use `\.`.

Comment: And what is `!.*` ? I understand the rest

Comment: It is a _negative lookahead_ assertion.  It means this: from the start of the string look ahead and verify that we _don't_ see two dots anywhere in the string.  Well if we don't see two dots, then there also cannot be more than two dots, implying there is only one or zero dots.  It does not match or consume anything, it just asserts the absence of two or more dots.

Comment: This seems like an expensive way to do things. The entire string could be scanned twice, with multiple backtracking along the way.

Comment: @TedHopp I actually prefer your answer, but I don't choose the accepted answer.

Comment: Well, you certainly deserve credit for coming up with a working regex first. My answer went through an embarrassing number of edits before I got it right. :(

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
^[A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9]*(\.[A-Za-z0-9]+)?$
```

This could probably be more concise, but it requires a letter at first followed by an arbitrary number of alphanumeric characters. After that, there's (optionally) a period followed by more alphanumeric characters.

Comment: No digit is allowed as the first character.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen By that logic, how's his different than my comment? My comment predated his answer.

Comment: Sorry buddy...didn't see that +1  Yeah, I found it odd that someone at your rep level would be poaching :-)

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen No problem :)

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
^\p{IsAlphabetic}\w*(\.\w+)?$
```

That matches an alphabetic character first, then any number of word characters, then, optionally, a single dot followed by at least one word character.

If your version of Java doesn't support the Unicode character classes defined in Java's [Pattern class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html), you can do this using Posix classes:

```
^\p{Alpha}\w*(\.\w+)?$
```

or, failing all else, your own explicit classes:

```
^[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z_0-9]*(\.[a-zA-Z_0-9]+)?$
```

(Note that I've allowed the `_` character to be consistent with Java's definition of what constitutes a "word" character (`\w`). Just remove it if not desired.)

Comment: Is this for Java ? what is `IsAlphabetic` ? It has invalid escape characters: `Invalid escape sequence (valid ones are  \b  \t  \n  \f  \r  \"  \'  \\ )`

Comment: This misses the edge case of a single letter only.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen - Oops. It also requires a dot, which OP doesn't require. I think it's now fixed.

Comment: @ArianHosseinzadeh - According to [the docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html), `\p{IsAlphabetic}` is a standard predefined character class. What version of Java are you using?

Comment: @ArianHosseinzadeh - Ah crap. I left in the leading backslash from the character class. It should now work.

Comment: @ArianHosseinzadeh [Ted's regex is fine](https://regex101.com/r/K6R6wU/2) you simply added an extra slash at the beginning for some reason.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen - No, that was my fault. I had accidentally left the backslash in when I tried to get rid of the `\p{}` class.